# Animated Items Control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Does anyone know of a good, animated ItemsControl for Silverlight, or an easy way to implement it?

Bascially, I am looking for something that allows the items to fly in/out when the items are added/removed from the ItemsSource.

I tried re-templating the ItemsControl to use the RadWrapPanel from Telerik, but that wasn't quite what I was looking for.  Realistically, an animated StackPanel would be nice.

I have also seen examples of doing this in Silverlight 4, but not with Silverlight 3.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in the Blacklight project ([here](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/) and [here](http://www.codeplex.com/blacklight)).  It has an animated layout panel that might do what you need.  I've used it successfully on various projects.

Comment: Yes, I got that working.  I needed something that acted like a StackPanel -- the content stretches to the width of the panel.  I accomplished this by deriving from AnimatedLayoutPanel and setting the width of the content children.  Works beautifully.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the SL4 examples you saw use features only available in SL4, you should be able to adapt the example to SL3.

Comment: Yes, the implementation uses SL4 specific capabilities: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/jesseliberty/archive/2009/11/20/silverlight-4-fluid-ui.aspx